# how i can reread my config file in runtime spring?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, config

The configuration file (application.yml) lies on the server, but there was a difficulty in the fact that after any change, you need to restart the docker. How can I reread it while the server is running?

Comment: ideally: integrate it with something like https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config

Answer (score 0):

There is a method refresh() in ConfigurableEnvironment class:

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

public void refresh() {
    env.getPropertySources().get("customProperties").getSource().refresh();
}
```